# Can't add back VSTO add-in after removing it

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I create VSTO outlook add-in and create installer using WIX. It works okay. But if I remove add-in using File->Options->Add-ins->Manage Com Add-ins->Remove
and then try to add it back using File->Options->Add-ins->Manage Com Add-ins->Add it shows error - "xxxxx/MyAddIn.dll is not valid Office Add-in".
What can be the problem? Does it same for all VSTO add-ins?

Answer (score 0):

It is for unmanaged add-ins that implement the IDTExtensibility2 interface. In case of VSTO based add-in a loader file should be shown there typically. You need to build the add-in project in Visual Studio if you want to get it back in Office applications. Or just add the required windows registry keys for the add-in, see [Registry Entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.